# Twitter Bootstrap - can't click on some form areas, but can tab to them

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having created a simple registration form using Twitter Bootstrap for the UI, I find that I've run into an unexpected problem. You see, some of the form rows are clickable, whereas some of them are not. However, you can tab over to all of the rows and enter information, which then writes correctly to the database. So, my guess is that it's a CSS problem. I haven't written any JavaScript that should cause this problem.

Anyone have any ideas? The page can be found here:

http://loganswalk.com/efc/efc/registration.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `form-horizontal` class to your form:

```
<form class="form-signin form-horizontal" role="form" action="registration.php" method="post">
```

Looking at your html I figured that you are using a horizontal form but you are not quite following the **[bootstrap 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)** . And also you are adding your own extra css to effect the left and right margin of the col-md-x classes (which is not a good idea) to make it look ok. Try following the example in the documentation closely and avoid changing the left and right margin or padding of any col-x-y class.

Comment: Thank you! Adding form-horizontal to the class was definitely the answer. I also got right of the extra CSS. Much appreciated.